# Batch or VB script to initiate Win7 RunAs login box?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, runas

I'm looking for a batch command or VBscript to execute what would a Shift+Right-click > "Run as different user" It pops up with a login box that just says "Windows Security" in the title

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2illN.jpg

I've searched far and wide and the closest I've gotten was the "runas" from the command line, and I've found a VBscript that can do "Run as administrator." But I just want a script that will initiate a login box like in the picture above, which is the same as the "Run as different user"

Thanks

Edit - Some background of my issue:
I have a batch file that I use to install software to remote computer via psexec, as well as running some scripts and stuff. Now in order to run my batch file successfully, the user will need to run it under a domain admin account. And I'm basically trying to force that to happen.

At first I tried forcing the UAC to come up via [this beautiful script](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin)...and that works great! Unfortunately I found out that will not work if a local administrator is logged on and launches the file (it will see that it already has admin rights on the local machine, but it won't have rights on the remote machine when it goes to run psexec).

I can't really do a runas via batch because I don't know what domain admin is going to be running the batch. I also would rather not have the user enter their credentials in a command line window...And I could just tell them to do the shift+right-click on the bat file, but I'd like to avoid that if possible, since users can be forgetful :)

So the solution to my problem, I believe, is a script that will do exactly what a Shift+right-click > "Run as different user" will do.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Shverb - Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu)**

Drag and drop or use in a command line.

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo Cmd.doit 
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

also

```
wmic /node"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /user:username /password:password /failfast:on process call create c:\somefile.bat
```

Comment: Runas /user:%userdomain%\%username% "notepad \"my file.txt\"" Admin will be prompted for their password. Passwords are hidden in the cmd prompt just like dialogs.

Comment: Runas /user:%userdomain%\%username% "notepad \"my file.txt\"" This is asks the user to enter their credentials into the cmd line. It doesn't pop up a login box like in the picture. Hope that make sense

Comment: And for that, I am thankful. Unfortunately I can't decipher what the VBscript even does, I cannot get it to run. And for the second one, I also cannot get that to run. Perhaps I'm a newbie and need to research the topic more before I can understand your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It has help built in. The first three lines are the help file.

```
  ShVerb

  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder


    ShVerb <filename> [verb]


  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder


  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator

  of the menu work when used this way


  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running

  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying

  a message box.
```

You'll have to run it on the remote system.

But the two command line tools allow passwords to be entered. And as I've shown you can put the user name in automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only verb that I know would be relevant is "run as" but that just elevates with UAC. I don't want the user name to be automatically populated. I want a script that I can put at the top of my batch file that operates like the "batch got admin" script I have linked in the OP. The only difference is, instead of it elevating the bat file, I want it to pop up with a login box as I have pictured.